# Access text of an HTML element in an EventListener function

Tags: javascript

I have a table of about two dozen cells, each containing some text. I'd like to copy the text of a cell when it is clicked.
My `<td>` elements don't have IDs.

I have this js code that allows me to put an `onClick()` event to all of them, and they do prompt the "Hello" message :

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert("hello");
    });
}
```

How do I access the text elements from within the EventListener's function ?

Comment: Try: `x[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        alert(e.target.textContent);
    });`

Comment: @nickzoum welp that made it, thank you :)

Comment: You should still accept one of the two answers

Comment: @nickzoum I will, when the minimum time will have passed

Comment: Main difference between `textContent` and `innerText` is that `textContent` will also return any text that is invisible unlike `innerText`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **`Event.target`** and get its `innerText`.

> **Event.target**: is the element on which the event is occurred.

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        alert(e.target.innerText);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can refer the currently clicked *td* with [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword. Then simply access [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) or [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property on that like `this.textContent`:

```
x[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert(this.textContent);
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert(this.textContent);
    });
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery you can do it this way:
table1 is class name of table

```
$(".table1 td").on("click", function(){
        var thisCell = $(this).html();
            alert(thisCell);
    });
```